# memory addresses and variable sizes -- are they related or not

Tags: c, stack

if I have this code

```
void foo(char *s)
{
    char buf[8];
    strcpy(buf, s);
    return;
}
```

can this be the stack layout for above code from this https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/135786/if-the-stack-grows-downwards-how-can-a-buffer-overflow-overwrite-content-above

```
  <---- stack grows to the left
    memory addresses increase to the right -->
  0x8000                     
  +--------+----------+---------++------------
  + buf[8] | ret addr | char *s ||   ....... 
  +--------+----------+---------++--------------
   <--------- foo() ----------->  <---- caller --
```

I like to know does memory addresses are linked to sizeof local variables, return address,and parameters on stack
so I have sizeof `char buf[8]` 8 bytes means in memory at least 8 bytes needed to store `buf`  so what can be, in a way, correct guess that the starting address of `return addr` in above layout will be? I think can it be `0x8000+ 8 bytes(skipping 8 types for char buf[8])`

can it possibly or I am not understanding it

Comment: The stack-frame of a function first of all depends on the compiler being used, and the ABI of the target platform. For example there's ABI's where arguments are passed in registers, and the compiler might add other information to the frame as well as padding and other empty areas around variables.

Comment: So if I am calling the function in loop just check different sizes of s so can it hit return address at some point?

Comment: Yes. That's how buffer overflow works. Use a debugger to see addresses and stack frame. You may need to turn off optimization when you compile.

Comment: @stark how to view addresses and stack frame in gdb. Can u please tell

Comment: LMGTFY https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/